# Is it ok to compile files with different gcc optimization levels for same application?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization

I have an application which generally used the gcc optimization flag -O0 (no optimization). Now I have a file opt.c which I would like to compile with -O1, and leave rest of the files with -O0.

To be more specific, opt.c has a large for loop, which performs some simple arithmetic.

Finally only 1 executable is created which has all the files plus the opt.c. I am not sure if this causes any issue!

Comment: GCC recommends -Og over -O0 for debug. Then you probably don't need different flags. But -O2 or -O3 for opt.c, could help a lot unless it compiles too slowly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's absolutely fine.  I'm curious why you don't wan't all of your code optimized?  We typically optimize everything, except a few files where optimization causes problems.

Comment: As it is a large application, there could be a possibility of error introduction (?) and would require additional testing. To avoid this, it is applied on one file.

Comment: @kp11 Optimizations causes problems only when either there are bugs in the code or, much less likely, there are bugs in the compiler or the toolchain. It's highly recommended that you maximally optimize all your code and resolve any resulting issues. That said, I approve this answer.

Comment: @HadiBrais: In some cases, optimizations can also wreak havoc on code written for dialects of C which offer useful behaviors and guarantees beyond those mandated by the Standard; in some cases, the runtime cost of disabling an obtuse compiler's "optimization" may be less than the cost of the code which would otherwise be required to guard against it.

Comment: I'm working for a SSD storage team. While I want optimization for speed of read/write related modules for best IO performance, I also want optimization for code space for other modules (temperature, error handling, firmware startup, etc) for smallest firmware size. Smaller firmware gives faster device ready time and requires fewer SPI flash space usage.